# What Nusach did the Twansa use?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, prayer-book, nuschaot

In most of the places that Sefardim settled after being kicked out of Iberia, there were already Jews living there, usually called "Musta'arabi". In most places, these communities intermingled to create the communities usually called "Mizrachi" today, but in some places, the two groups remained separate. I know this to be true in a few places, notably Morocco, Malabar in India, and Tunisia. In Morocco, the non-Sephardim are known as "Toshavim", and they have their own Nusach. In Malabar, the non-Sephardim are known as "Cochinim", and they, too, have their own Nusach. In Tunisia, these Musta'arabim are called "[Twansa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Tunisia#Granas_and_Twansa)", but I can't find any information as to what Nusach they use. Did they use the same Musta'arabi rite as the Toshavim? Did they use Edot Hamizrach even though they were distinct from the Sephardim? Did they have their own Nusach? If the latter, where might I be able to find information on this Nusach or perhaps even find a siddur?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ben and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Some useful background reading here - https://dokumen.pub/sephardi-and-middle-eastern-jewries-history-and-culture-0253330130-9780253330130.html

Comment: Do you think maybe they might have used something close to [siddur tefilat hahodesh](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9) or some other livorno siddur? see here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/livorno-siddurim

Comment: According to this document the first North African must'arabi siddurim were published in Algiers and the same nusach was followed in Tripoli and Tunis. The link contains a reference to a book on early Jewish printing in North Africa which would presumably furnish the information you're looking for: https://dokumen.pub › sephar...PDF
Sephardi and Middle Eastern Jewries - DOKUMEN.PUB

Comment: https://dokumen.pub/qdownload/sephardi-and-middle-eastern-jewries-history-and-culture-0253330130-9780253330130.html